# Is there any way to find and reverse encryption being done inside of a unity WebGL game?

Tags: unity-webgl

There is a Unity WebGL game hosted online that posts level data to a server. This data is sent raw in JSON packets, but has a 256 bit string along with it that the server uses to verify the data. I know that this is probably generated within the local WebGL game, so the encryption key must be accessible somehow. I also don't know if encryption is the right word for this process, so if you know then please leave a comment.

I tried opening the raw WASM file to look for something, but it is very low-level assembly code and was hard to read. I opened up the .data file using a tool but only found sprite images. The javascript of the website was also very obfuscated, with only letters as functions and nothing notable to be found there.

Comment: it's probably a little more complicated. Likely taking a challenge/response, so that each session encrypts with a different challenge, so you cannot replicate. You need the algorithm, the challenge, and potentially any keys to cheat. There are likely other serverside checks, checking for impossibly quick or sudden actions, as well. good luck.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Its only a single http post and I don't think there are any other server checks. If I use a manual packet sender and copy the data, it posts it perfectly fine. I believe that it is as simple as just finding the algorithm for the single encryption.